# Estimating Population Mean from Samples of Different Sizes

Tags: clustering, sample-size, hierarchical-clustering

This is a super-simple question, but I've run into this problem a number of times and I haven't known how to solve it or even what this issue is called.

Suppose I have a dataset consisting of 29 observations: 10 each from person A and person B, and 3 from person C, person D, and person E. Now, I want to estimate the expected value of an observation from a new person, person F (suppose too that there's no structural reason why persons A and B appear more in the sample, and person F is no more similar to them than person F is to C-E). But the estimates for persons A and B are more precise, so I want to weight them more. How much more? I think that depends on how much of the variance is within-group versus between-group, but I don't know the right estimator here.

I believe the data generating process for observation j from person i looks like
$\text{val}_{ij} = \mu + \gamma_i + \epsilon$, where $\gamma$ and $\epsilon$ are normally distributed with mean 0 and variances $\sigma_\gamma$ and $\sigma_\epsilon$.

If I thought $\sigma_\gamma$ was 0, which is very easy to test, I could just pool them all. If I didn't care about efficiency, I could just calculate all the group means, take the mean of that, and if I have enough groups, I get a good estimate.

But the right answer has to be a weighted average of the group means, taking into account that 10 observations from person A are more informative than 3 observations from person C, but less informative than 9 observations from persons C, D, and E.

I've run into issues with grouping to which the answer was clustered standard errors, which of course are appropriate in this setting, but I don't know how to get a point estimate here.

Below is some R code where weighting by the square root of the group size is a better estimator than either the overall mean or the mean of the group means, but that's only the case for some parameter values.

Thanks for your help!

````
library(Hmisc)
library(data.table)
library(foreach)

true_mean = 0
n_big_group = 200
n_small_group = 40
n_groups_big_group = 10
n_groups_small_group = 50
n_groups = n_groups_big_group + n_groups_small_group
within_group_sd = 0.1

estimates =
  foreach(seed = 1:500, .combine = rbind) %do% {
    set.seed(seed)
    data = data.table(id = c(rep(1:n_groups_big_group, times = n_big_group),
                             rep((n_groups_big_group + 1):n_groups, times = n_small_group))
                    )[data.table(id = 1:n_groups, within_group_noise = rnorm(n_groups, sd = within_group_sd)), on = .(id)
                    ][, val := true_mean + within_group_noise + rnorm(n_big_group * n_groups_big_group + n_small_group * n_groups_small_group)]
    
    data.table(unbinned = mean(data$val),
           binned = mean(data[, .(val = mean(val)), id]$val),
               my_estimate = data[, .(my_weight = sqrt(.N), val = mean(val)), id
                                ][, Hmisc::wtd.mean(val, weights = my_weight)])
  }

# RMSE
estimates[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sqrt(mean((x - true_mean)^2)))]

#   unbinned     binned my_estimate
# 0.02365728 0.02244304  0.02165596
```
````